# Scaleform BitmapData: Invalid Bitmapdata

Tags: actionscript-3, scaleform

I'm trying to add a "on fire effect" to our UI.
I am achieving this using BitmapData and PerlinNoise and some others.

The issue comes when anything I do with the BitmapData causes this error:

```
 ArgumentError: Error #2015: Argument error: Invalid BitmapData.
    at effects::FireFX/updateBitmaps()...
```

Something as simple as this will cause the error to show up.

```
displayBmp = new BitmapData(200, 200, true, 0);
scratchBmp = displayBmp.clone();
```

In my case, functions like clone() or perlinNoise() or colorTransform.... etc... are causing the crash.

Debugging / Running it under Animate CC works just fine.

PD: Publishing to Flash 10.3, using Scaleform: 4.1.19

Thanks

Comment: Error 2015 might be caused by zero width or height of the `BitmapData`

Comment: Check if you don't go out of memory.

Comment: Does it work if you don't involve Scaleform? Using just AS3 code to declare `var displayBmp : BitmapData;` and `var scratchBmp : BitmapData;` I could then use your shown code to clone without issues. Even traced `scratchBmp.width` as 200. Maybe you should post a **complete yet minimal** code for us to test/recreate your issue.

Comment: Everything works without scaleform. Width and Height have been tested as mentioned above, which was sufficient for causing the crash.

Comment: Sorry buddy, I read too fast last time. No clue then. If it was my problem I'd be trying example `new BitmapData(200, 200, false, 0xFF0000);` just to be sure that between your shown `transparency=true` & color hex of `0` it's not making an empty bitmapdata with no pixels to clone. At least try `displayBmp.draw(something);` before using `.clone`. If still invalid data after `.draw`ing then you have an issue elsewhere...

Comment: @VC.One

Just doing:

var displayBmp:BitmapData;   
   displayBmp = new BitmapData(200, 200, false, 0xFF0000);
   displayBmp.draw(this);

Was enough to make it throw the error. Works just fine in the Animate Debugger.

Comment: Since it works fine in Flash Player (debugger), can you confirm that Scaleform itself actually supports any bitmapData API methods? Check its documentation...

Comment: @VC.One I can't find the document for the version I have, and nobody seems to know.

Comment: In my experience, if cloning bitmapdata works in the IDE but not in the player, you may have a security issue. It depends on where the image data is coming from. Images from external domains cannot be cloned.

Answer (score 1):

Scaleform does support the BitmapData API, as of version 4.1 ([reference](http://help.autodesk.com/view/SCLFRM/ENU/?guid=__scaleform_help_flash_support_as3_class_html)). However, 4.1.19 was the first release of 4.1, and thus the initial release with BitmapData support. You may want to upgrade to a newer version, as there have certainly been fixes to the BitmapData support since its initial release.

The most common reason to get this error, is to not pass a `ThreadCommandQueue` instance into [`MovieDef::CreateInstance`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/SCLFRM/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_01124_html) as the last parameter, and BitmapData operations are used on the first frame. Without an instance of the `ThreadCommandQueue`, the renderer cannot create the backing for the BitmapData objects within Scaleform. A more descriptive warning was added to Scaleform in later versions.

For `ThreadCommandQueue`, you generally need to implement this yourself, to integrate properly with your application's rendering code. The simplest multi-threaded implementation would simply store `ThreadCommand` objects in a (thread-safe) list, when called from `PushThreadCommand`, and call `Execute` on the objects at some point during the application render loop.

In later versions of the SDK, there is a class provided called [`SingleThreadedCommandQueue`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/SCLFRM/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_06044_htm%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bl), which provides an basic implementation that will execute all commands immediately. This only works if you are using `Movie::Advance` and `HAL::Display` on the same thread. You can see a more complex version of a `ThreadCommandQueue` implementation, used in the Scaleform samples from the `RenderHALThread` class, which defers most of the important implementation to `RTCommandQueue`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, very appreciated. How would I go about Initializing a RenderThread class ín order to pass it on to the HAL constructor, can't find any documentation on that.

Comment: 'RenderThread' class isn't really required. You could reuse the ones in the samples (in Src/Platform), if you wanted. If you're integrating it a multi-threaded rendering application, you only need to provide an implementation of ThreadCommandQueue. If you are single threaded, you can use SingleThreadedCommandQueue (http://help.autodesk.com/view/SCLFRM/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_06044_html).

Comment: I can't Create an instance of ThreadCommandQueue as the class is practically empty. No way to initialize or implement in any way. I dont have the SingleThreadedCommandQueue either.

Comment: SingleThreadedCommandQueue is provided in later versions of the SDK. You do not instantiate ThreadCommandQueue directly, you must implement a derived class.

Comment: Could you post a example of what you mean? I have never really worked on the Code Part of Scaleform. Thanks